# Returning empty string when attribute does not match return text when attribute matches

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I need to be able to keep track of where in the document any particular value is.  I would use XSL but the ecosystem I'm working in prevents that.   I'm using the Java Saxon-HE 9.7.0-2 processor.

XML

```
<test>
    <value cat="fiction">At the edge of the orchard</value>
    <value cat="mythology">Hero with a thousand faces</value>
    <value cat="fiction">Spill simmer falter wither</value>
</test>
```

XPath

```
for $a in /test
    return
        (if ($a/value[@cat="mythology"]) then 
            $a/value[@cat="mythology"] else
            "")
```

What I would like to see come back is:

```
""
"Hero with a thousand faces"
""
```

What I'm currently seeing is:

```
"Hero with a thousand faces"
```

[Link to videlibri xpath tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctest%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22fiction%22%3EAt%20the%20edge%20of%20the%20orchard%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22mythology%22%3EHero%20with%20a%20thousand%20faces%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22fiction%22%3ESpring%2C%20summer%2C%20spring%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%3C%2Ftest%3E&=&extract=for%20%24a%20in%20%2Ftest%0A%20%20%20%20return%0A%09%09(if%20(%24a%2Fvalue%5B%40cat%3D%22mythology%22%5D)%20then%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24a%2Fvalue%5B%40cat%3D%22mythology%22%5D%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22)&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

[Link to saxon code](https://gist.github.com/BDF/549959faeadc056307d8be11530bbc1c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to iterate on every `value` and do the check. The below xpath should work for you:

```
string-join((for $a in /test/value
                                return
                                    (if ($a[@cat='mythology']) then 
                                        concat('&quot;',$a,'&quot;') else
                                        '&quot;&quot;')),'&#xa;')
```

Simplified:

```
string-join((for $a in /test/value
            return
                concat('&quot;',($a[@cat='mythology'],'')[1], '&quot;'))
     ,'&#xa;')
```

Comment: Thank you; it is closer to what I need but now I'm in the position of having a to parse the return.    What I get with this xPath is: &quot;&quot;&#xa;&quot;Hero with a thousand faces&quot;&#xa;&quot;&quot;           Parsing that is risky for me because in reality what is in that block of text is unconstrained.  I still may have to go with this solution if I can't come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

This is returning the empty strings I'm looking for:

```
for $a in /test/value
return
    if ($a[@cat='mythology']) then 
        $a[@cat='mythology'] else
        ""
```

Can someone explain why this xpath behaves differently from the one in the original question?

[videlibri xpath tester](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctest%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22fiction%22%3EAt%20the%20edge%20of%20the%20orchard%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22mythology%22%3EHero%20with%20a%20thousand%20faces%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%20%20%3Cvalue%20cat%3D%22fiction%22%3ESpring%2C%20summer%2C%20spring%3C%2Fvalue%3E%0A%3C%2Ftest%3E&=&extract=for%20%24a%20in%20%2Ftest%2Fvalue%0A%09return%0A%20%20%20%20%09if%20(%24a%5B%40cat%3D%27mythology%27%5D)%20then%20%0A%09%09%09%24a%5B%40cat%3D%27mythology%27%5D%20else%0A%09%09%09%22%22&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath2)

Comment: To answer my own question:   The original loop of 'for $a in /test' is only one node so the containing if statement only ever gets evaluated once.   In the version that works; I'm iterating over multiple nodes.     This was made clear to me when I evaluated     /test/value[@cat='fiction']   by itself without the loop and if statements.     Another thank you for lingamurthy for getting me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

I think `/test/value/(.[@cat = 'mythology'], '')[1]` suffices and is a bit more compact than the `for .. return if ... then ... else`.